# HTML Change Dyanmically with JQuery when I clicked the Link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work out how this can be achieved using jQuery,　I have 3 Html Pages.
Page 1 is a frame Html Page ,it contains one link and one empty div.
Page 2 contains only one link too.
Page 3 contains only one Paragraph.

I inserted Page 2 to empty div from Page 1 when Page 1 is load. So when the window load, It has two links.
I want to make these two links to connect to Page3.

But,Only link from Page1 can connect that.
Dynamically loaded link from the Page 2 cannot connect.
I used Jquery to connect  Pages and all Jquery code are at Page1.

Has anyone any tutorials that are similar to this?

My Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#container').load('page2.html #linkfrompage2') ;

        $('#link1').click(function () 
        { 

            $('#container').load('page3.html #divfrompage3') ;
        }); 
        $('#link2').click(function () 
        { 

            $('#container').load('page3.html #divfrompage3') ;
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Isuggest, if you dont have much html content, then better include all the html content into a single page and do hide and show, depending on your requirement. Hope's that helpfull

Comment: that was testing page only,I still making with a lot of contents for that process.I can't do hide and show .I have the others

Comment: @LadyIvory Are these three seperate .html pages?

Comment: yes .same folder but separate html page

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1: Using Iframe. [See Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/YpZBL/)***

```
function changeFrame(url){
        $("#data").html('<iframe src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
}

$(".link").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("link");
    changeFrame(link);
});
```

***Solution 2: Using Ajax. [See Solution.(Page Not Found Eroor is seen because page1.html is not in this server. Anyaway it works with correct Links)](http://jsfiddle.net/YpZBL/1/)***
**Update: For Multiple Divs: http://jsfiddle.net/YpZBL/5/**

```
 $(".link").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("link");
        $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url:link,
        success: function(result){
            $("data").html(result);
        }
  });
});
```

*I personally prefer AJAX but you need to watch out for **Same Origin Policy**. You cannot Load a file from another Server. For, that you need JSONP. IF you have files in the same serevr, use Second Solution.*

Comment: Can I use JQuery only for that or Java Script.IFrame is not suitable for me.I don't like that.and Two links but only one target.

Comment: @LadyIvory Use JQuery as it is quicker. You can also do this way: http://jsfiddle.net/YpZBL/4/ in Javascript. You can also change the target: By Making multiple divs for multiple links.

Comment: original first link is worked,but second link which come from dynamic is not worked.btw,these two links go same target.

Comment: @LadyIvory If you want the result in different divs, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/YpZBL/5/

Comment: No,u don't understand my question, ur answers are worked well. But that not for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58223/discussion-between-xdnp-and-lady-ivory).

Comment: I  mean at Least I could understand what you are trying to achieve through JSFIddle.